# How to extract all Chatter messages of a user in Apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, chatter

I want to do some language analysis based on Chatter messages and never manipulated Chatter with Apex code before.

How would I get all the Chatter message text of a certain user?
Would I need to directly talk to REST APIs or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For something like that, you might be better off just querying FeedItem:

```
Feeditem [] fi = [Select Id, body, ParentId from FeedItem WHERE CreatedById = '00580000003akT6'];
```

The ConnectAPI is setup to do searches across feeds etc, but it typically expects you to provide a search  query. I don't see a method to just retrieve all activity for a user.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really done anything with Chatter in Apex either, but I can at least point you to the place to start looking for answers.  Check out [Working with Chatter in Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/connectAPI_overview.htm) and the [Connect API](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_classes_connect_api.htm), which is the API for working with Chatter in Apex.  From what I have read, you should be able to read the messages of users, as long as the Apex is running as a user with View All Data privileges.